# How can I buy my own personalized Top Level Domain (TLD)?

Tags: domain-registration, top-level-domains

Starting fomm tomorrow January/12/2012 I heard it's possible to apply for your own TLD i.e. `.whatever` in place of `.com` `.org` etc.

I thought it would require a huge amount of money (I heard stories about paying $185K for one) but I found a company that seems to register a new TLD for just $1000.

> The price to register a TLD including the unlimited number of domains
> that belong to it is: $1000.- only.

Do you think this is a scam or for real? Do you know about any other places where I can go to apply for personalized TLD?

Comment: Just for the cost of hosting, you can create your own root DNS and own all the TLDs provided by that root.  Of course, almost no one will be using your root DNS, even if you try to promote it heavily.

Comment: Funny aftermath: the link you gave now results in a page saying: "Notice: This domain name expired on 05/21/18 and is pending renewal or deletion" It seems that "selling" TLDs at just $1000 was not exactly profitable/future-proof.

Comment: When I click on the link => this company ____

from above Norton Antivirus detected an attack. 
Moderators please check
An intrusion attempt by tld.name was blocked
Web Attack: Rig Exploit Kit Redirection 13
tld.name/register-you-tld.php

Comment: @DmitriLarionov fixed by removing links, thanks

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The site you saw is run by Public-Root, one of the many [alternative root zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_DNS_root#Public-Root) operators. These are essentially rogue organizations that create/sell custom TLDs that aren't sanctioned or recognized by ICANN and only exist on their own private root DNS servers.

So, technically, they're right, you can buy a custom TLD from them for $1000. The only problem is that no one, not even you, will be able to resolve the TLD or any domains under that TLD because pretty much no ISPs use these alternative root DNS zones. Nearly all ISPs stick to ICANN's official DNS root.

Another problem with alternative root zones is that it allows different root zone operators to sell the same FQDN to different people, resolving to different servers. This happened when Pacific Root created `.biz` before ICANN sanctioned the creation of the `.biz` TLD. Later, when ICANN officially sanctioned `.biz` and delegated it to Neulevel's root servers, there became a conflict due to overlapping DNS records for `.biz` domains sold by Pacific Root and those sold by Neulevel. In effect, some people would type in `foo.biz` and it would resolve to one IP address as given by Pacific Root, while someone with a different ISP would get pointed to another IP as specified in Neulevel's official root servers.

Of course, this was gradually resolved as alternative root zones have pretty much been discounted (as evidenced by the horribly dated and poorly maintained self-promotional websites linked to Public-Root) since the use of alternative root zone would inevitably fracture and destabilize the internet. But this hasn't stopped these unethical companies from setting up semi-official-sounding organizations to link to using fake trustmarks (using early-90s-era graphics) and trying to scam unweary visitors out of their money.

Comment: You seem to be right, searching the site if found this info http://tld.name/check.php , it kind of confirms what you wrote.

Comment: To add to this excellent reply: many altermate roots provided you with instructions to change your DNS settings, to use other recursive nameservers than your ISP ones, in order to use some that "recognize" the new "private" TLDs. Some were so funny as to conflate domain and website and offer you a plugin to install in your browser so that you could input "whatever.myTLD" while in reality you were silently going to "whatever.myTLD.example.com" (that is a subdomain finally anchored at a TLD in the IANA root).

Comment: ICANN position on all of this (alternate roots) is recorded at https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/unique-authoritative-root-2012-02-25-en while the position of the technical community (IETF) is recorded at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2826

Answer (score 23):

It does appear that [ICANN will be allowing you to purchase your own TLD](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/), but I would be incredibly skeptical of any company offering to sell you one - especially right now.

It looks like ICANN will start taking applications on Wednesday, Jan. 12th (tomorrow, on the date of this answer) and will be accepting applications up until April.

I have not been able to find a price from anywhere other than this [TechCrunch Article about the new TLD decision](http://techcrunch.com/2011/06/20/icann-to-expand-top-level-domain-names-applications-start-jan-12-2012/), and that quotes the $185,000 figure as well.

It sounds like someone is trying to scam you out of $1000 - I'd be very wary!

**EDIT**: According to the [Application Guidebook](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb/guidebook-full-11jan12-en.pdf) from the [ICANN New gTLD site](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/), the registration fee is indeed $185,000. Unless these registrars are kindly footing the bill for the initial cost, I would highly doubt their legitimacy.

If you're interested in applying for one, I'd say the ICANN program site will be your best bet.

If you are successful in your application, there are then ongoing fees (from [FAQ 5.7](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/customer-service/faqs/faqs-en)):

- A fixed fee of US$6,250 per calendar quarter
- A transaction fee of US$0.25 (once you have more than 50,000 transactions per quarter/4 quarters)

There are also other fees that may be required during the registration process to cover the costs of arbitration panels if more than one person attempts to register a similar TLD.

Comment: Looks very real, but I like to see someone try it first

Comment: The *registration* fee is $185k, there are then quaterly fees on top of that just to maintain the domain, etc.

Comment: Google bought the ".google" TLD

Comment: google also recently got `.app`

Comment: You left an important point of this process: these TLD openings were restricted to organizations, not individuals. It is true that one TLD was a family name... but just because the guy named one of its company with its own family name.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid This is far from the last fee to pay. Also it is not a "registration" fee but an "application" fee that is a mandatory amount to pay just to be able to give your application, without any guarantee of success. Because, for example, they were multiple applications for `.APP` so only one could prevail but all need to pay (reason given: the applications still need to be reviewed on various criterias)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  at the time of writing my comment (6 years ago) it was referred to as a registration fee all be it with no guarantee of success. I also stated that there were ongoing fees to pay as well which Jacob then edited into his answer.

Comment: "it was referred to as a registration fee" source? I think in contrary that it was always an "application fee", because otherwise registration hints that you get it, like registering a domain name. But this is indeed not very important now: There are not only other ongoing fees, there are as well other setup fees, like accreditation and connection to the TMDB.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I've just checked the linked documentation in Jacob's answer from ICANN (gTLD Applicant Guidebook Version 2012-01-11) which calls it an "Evaluation Fee" (see section 1.5.1). So we're both wrong. Section 1.5.2 listed "Fees required in some cases", and as far as a brief search can find the TMDB was only fully launched in 2013, and so couldn't have been included in either this answer or my comments. 1/2

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  However, to be honest, this was (probably - I can't speak for Jacob) intended to be a basic overview of the official process for setting up a recognised gTLD rather than using the OPs finding of an offer to do so for only $1,000. 2/2

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid I was not saying the answer was wrong I was just providing additional input now that we are far after this process, in order for future readers coming here to have a better picture.

Comment: No worries :) - If you're trying to present additional details for future users, that can be done through editing the answer with up-to-date information (including links to sources) because all I could find this morning was the original proposal site, which required you to have joined up back in 2012!